# Retrieving sidHistory from LDAP with Java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I can retrieve objectSID and many other attributes without error, but not sidHistory (I need sidHistory to see which account in domain A corresponds to an account in domain B).

Here's the code that works for most attributes, including objectSID:

```
void dumpCSV(Attributes attrs, String[] displayList, Logger lg)  {
    // Assume we're only dealing with single valued attributes (for now)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String attName : displayList)  {
        String name = attName.trim().toLowerCase();
        Attribute att = attrs.get(name);
        if (sb.length() > 0)
            sb.append(",");
        if (att != null)  {
            String v = "?";
            try  {
                if ((name.equals("objectsid")) || (name.equals("sidhistory")))
                    v = binString(att);
                else  {
                    v = (String) att.get();
                    if (name.equals("pwdlastset") || name.equals("lastlogontimestamp") || name.equals("lastlogon") || name.equals("accountexpires"))
                        v = TickConverter.tickDate(v);
                }
                sb.append(Logger.tidyString(v));
            } catch (NamingException e)  {
                System.err.println("NamingException, " + e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
        lg.logln(sb.toString());
    }
}

static String binString(Attribute att)  {
    try  {
        byte bin[] = (byte[]) att.get();
        return decodeSID(bin);
    } catch (NamingException e)  {
        System.err.println("NamingException, " + e);
        return "?";
    }
}

// taken from http://www.adamretter.org.uk/blog/entries/LDAPTest.java, in turn borrowed from Oracle docs
public static String decodeSID(byte[] sid) {
    final StringBuilder strSid = new StringBuilder("S-");

    // get version
    final int revision = sid[0];
    strSid.append(Integer.toString(revision));

    //next byte is the count of sub-authorities
    final int countSubAuths = sid[1] & 0xFF;

    //get the authority
    long authority = 0;
    //String rid = "";
    for(int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
       authority |= ((long)sid[i]) << (8 * (5 - (i - 2)));
    }
    strSid.append("-");
    strSid.append(Long.toHexString(authority));

    //iterate all the sub-auths
    int offset = 8;
    int size = 4; //4 bytes for each sub auth
    for(int j = 0; j < countSubAuths; j++) {
        long subAuthority = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            subAuthority |= (long)(sid[offset + k] & 0xFF) << (8 * k);
        }

        strSid.append("-");
        strSid.append(subAuthority);

        offset += size;
    }

    return strSid.toString();    
}
```

If I try to retrieve sidHistory using this, tyhe value I get is "?".

Even if I use a namingEnumeration, as I think I probably should, I get "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Vector Enumeration", probably because I am trying to save it to the wrong typoe (and I've tried a few different types).

snippet is :

```
String v;
NamingEnumeration nenum = att.getAll();
while (nenum.hasMore())  {
    v = "";
    if (name.equals("objectsid"))  {
        v = binString(att);
        nenum.next();
    } else if (name.equals("sidhistory"))  {
         nenum.next();
         String[] vv = ((String[]) nenum.next());
         v = vv[0];
    } else
    v = (String) nenum.next();
    if (name.equals("pwdlastset") || name.equals("lastlogontimestamp") || name.equals("lastlogon") || name.equals("accountexpires"))
        v = TickConverter.tickDate(v);
    lg.logln(name + "=" + Logger.tidyString(v));
}
```

Comment: Searching the entire attribute set for attributes you're interested in is futile. You should retrieve the attributes you want, via `Attributes.get()`, and then look into their values. For one thing, your way is inefficient, and for another it overlooks case-insensitiveness of attribute names.

Comment: Hi EJP : I do that - notice " for (String attName : displayList)" and "    Attribute att = attrs.get(name)".  I specify the particular attributes I want in displayList[].

Comment: So why do you test the name afterwards? Why the loop? Why not just get the ones you actually want, via the names you want them by? Very strange code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used some code similar to: 
We note we saw it at [http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/realm/ActiveDirectoryRealm.html#L566](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/realm/activedirectoryrealm.html)

```
...
Attribute sidHistory = roleAttributes.get("sIDHistory;binary");
List<String> sidHistoryStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
if (sidHistory != null) 
{
  NamingEnumeration<?> sidHistoryEnum = sidHistory.getAll();
  while (sidHistoryEnum.hasMore()) 
  {
    byte[] sidHistoryBytes = (byte[]) sidHistoryEnum.next();
    sidHistoryStrings.add(new Sid(sidHistoryBytes).toString());
  }
...
}
```

[sidHistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679833(v=vs.85).aspx) is multi-valued and binary ([octetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684453(v=vs.85).aspx)) is what cause most people headaches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was after.